# Override Python Calendar HTMLCalendar CSS

Tags: python, django, calendar

I would like to override the default Python Calendar CSS. I am currently using the class calendar.HTMLCalendar and would like to override the default python calendar css.

What is the smartest way in overriding the default css? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I would like to use my calendar css.

-Keoko

Here is a sample of the templatetag that I am using:

```
  def formatday(self, day, weekday):
       if day != 0:
           cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
           if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
           cssclass += ' today'
       if day in self.readings:
           cssclass += ' filled'
           body = ['<ul>']
           for reading in self.readings[day]:
              body.append('<li>')
              body.append('<a href="%s">' % reading.get_absolute_url())
              body.append(esc(reading.series.primary_name))
              body.append('</a></li>')
           body.append('</ul>')
           return self.day_cell(cssclass, '<span class="dayNumber">%d</span> %s' %  (day, ''.join(body)))
        return self.day_cell(cssclass, '<span class="dayNumberNoReadings">%d</span>' % (day))
    return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')
```

Thanks again.

Comment: do you have sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly the rule you need to override, your CSS rule(s) simply have to be more specific than the rule that already exists. There are several ways to accomplish that, but it depends on what rules are already in place.

As a primer, take a look at: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/. It will give you some pointers as to how you can best override the styles you want to change.

Let's say you have the following styles coming from the Python Calendar CSS that you're implementing:

```
.calendar .day {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

To override this style, you could do:

```
table.calendar .day  // or

.calendar td.day  // or

table.calendar td.day
```

The calendar outputs a `<table>` for the month, with a CSS class of 'month' on the table, and 'month' for the `<th>` tag. So, to override the style, you could do:

```
table.month th.month {
  // your style here
}
```

But this isn't a very efficient selector, as the DOM will be searched for all of the table tags before it can apply the style. A much more efficient selector would be to wrap the calendar in a target `div` tag with an `id`:

```
#mycalendar .month .month {
  // your style
}
```

That specifically targets a div with the id of "mycalendar", so it doesn't have to loop over all of the tags.

You have to override the specificity of the CSS coming from the Python Calendar CSS code that they are supplying to you. The samples above provide a more specific selector. This is one of the most basic principles of *Cascading* Style Sheets (notice the emphasis on the "Cascading" part)

Comment: Hello Brandon - I am not quite sure what you mean by rule that already exist. Here is the sample code taken from my templatetag:

Comment: Thank you Brandon. I think I understand how to add the css for the day. How about for the month? Please see details below:

Comment: def formatmonth(self, year, month):
      self.year, self.month = year, month
      return super(ReadingCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

Comment: Unfortunately the CSS in embedded in the Python caledar.py file. For a full description of the calendar.py point your browser to http://coverage.livinglogic.de/Lib/calendar.py.html and scroll down between lines 376 to line 497.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. It is not the most elegant way but the trick was to embed the style sheet within the template. I just have to figure another way to separate the css from the code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample codes. Let's say we add class name in < ul > like this:

```
def formatday(self, day, weekday):
       if day != 0:
           cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
           if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
           cssclass += ' today'
       if day in self.readings:
           cssclass += ' filled'
           body = ['<ul class="sample">'] //<---------add class
           for reading in self.readings[day]:
              body.append('<li>')
              body.append('<a href="%s">' % reading.get_absolute_url())
              body.append(esc(reading.series.primary_name))
              body.append('</a></li>')
           body.append('</ul>')
           return self.day_cell(cssclass, '<span class="dayNumber">%d</span> %s' %  (day, ''.join(body)))
        return self.day_cell(cssclass, '<span class="dayNumberNoReadings">%d</span>' % (day))
    return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')
```

Then, in your css codes, you can simply write:

```
<style>
.sample {
    background:red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you Catherine. It seems to work. How would I wrap the content using tables and rows.

Comment: I think it's already wrap in tables, I see the link of your codes and he already specify tables for that calendar

Comment: If you have question again, I can't answer it. Need to sleep. I will answer it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developer tools allows you to inspect the page elements - just right click and click inspect and it'll pop up on the right. This way you can see the class assigned to each table element just by hovering over the area you want.

The below css is an example and the css tags should be correct for your calendar.

```
.filled{
    background-color: pink;
}
.today {
    background-color: #66ccff;
}
.noday{
    background-color: #f0f0f5;
}
.month {
    border:1px solid navy;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}
.month th {
    text-align: center;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
.month td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
}
```

Then just makes sure you import the .css into your template!

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="location-of-your-css-here" type='text/css' media='all'/>
```